# Assign Individual Objects to Each Python Multiprocessor Thread

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that I map multiple worker threads to execute. I would like each thread to maintain its own dictionary to write results from the function and finally, individually write the contents of each dictionary to seperate files. I would like to know how to accomplish this in Python. I found no clear way to assign an object to a single thread. The documentation is only covering information related to sharing memory between threads (with Manager objects). Following is the code I am using for the job (except for the current_thread_dict in worker, currently I use a Manager.dict which every thread use):

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    def worker(row):
         #add items to current_thread_dict


    with Pool(processes=16) as p:
         results = p.map(worker, rows, chunksize=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the row you could pass an index to each worker so that it knows in which file it has to save the dict. I implemented a simple example as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import json


def worker(args):
    i, row = args

    # create object
    current_thread_dict = {
        'row': row,
        'ind': i,
    }

    # add stuff to dict
    if not row.startswith('data'):
        current_thread_dict['special'] = row.upper()
    else:
        current_thread_dict['special'] = None
    current_thread_dict['summary'] = '{row} - {ind} (special: {special})'\
        .format(**current_thread_dict)

    # save dict
    with open(f'output{i}.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(current_thread_dict, f, indent=2)


def main():
    rows = ['data1', 'wow', 'data3', 'banana']
    with Pool(processes=16) as p:
        results = p.map(worker, enumerate(rows), chunksize=1)
    print('results:', results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope this was helpful!